# Bulk insert using Enterprise Library 5

Tags: bulkinsert, enterprise-library-5

How do I perform a bulk insert of records with just one call/trip, using Microsoft Enterprise Library 5?

Answer (score 1):

There is no clear cut method that the library provides to implement this as per my knowledge.
Following steps will help you implement bulk inserts using EntLib 5.0
-Implement a CustomTraceListener to override the TraceData method
-Pass the records in a serialized XML or something, as a param to the stored proc in DB
-Further processing can be done in the stored proc to read the XML and place each record into DB

This technique will avoid hitting the DB multiple times with just one call.
Hope it solves your problem.